# Get from "ID X" downwards in sorted LINQ IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, pagination

Say I have a Linq `IEnumerable` like such:

```
select new
{
  uniqueID = row.Field<string>("uuid")
} into records
orderby records.uniqueID
```

And it has the following contents:

```
2d40b775-c2fe-49a0-a62e-ed465cfc65ec
d5686fb3-8f92-41b1-b9bb-8f6e8743e658
72981553-445b-4958-8384-73512eac48af
1654e7dd-63c7-4f34-b6be-9ab84d76ffc8
9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213
67f0ba48-162e-4210-8772-8a44cda145b6
00a09170-cf71-47ae-a764-2f8eeb31f368
13637bc7-c74f-4435-94cb-76d6681052ac
ab98615e-8ceb-4876-8ac6-29a546298839
513b4313-5a9a-409d-9f46-045a09d3db42
```

I need to get all Guids from `9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213` downwards, given that they are sorted.
IE: The result I'm expecting to get is:

```
9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213
67f0ba48-162e-4210-8772-8a44cda145b6
00a09170-cf71-47ae-a764-2f8eeb31f368
13637bc7-c74f-4435-94cb-76d6681052ac
ab98615e-8ceb-4876-8ac6-29a546298839
513b4313-5a9a-409d-9f46-045a09d3db42
```

I'm curious to know if there is there a way to do this in LINQ, or is an old fashioned for loop the way to approach this?

Comment: Why not `descending` and why are you not using `Guid.Parse`?

Comment: I left some code out as I am adding a string prefix to the ID.

Comment: however, but you don't mention the rule for the ordering. I see that the numeric guid's are before the non-numeric but not always.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you mean. I did not sort the dataset I supplied, I just used them as a quick example

Comment: Then the question is not clear. You don't want to order, so what do you want? What means _"get all Guids from 9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213 downwards"_, do you want to filter them. If so, which do you want to  exclude?

Comment: Imagine the dataset I provided were sorted. I want to exclude the ones before `9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213`, given they were in alphabetical order.

Comment: you can use `SkipWhile` as nvoigt has already mentioned, you just have to use the condition `records.uniqueID != "9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213"`. But it seems to be somewhat arbitrary since a GUID has no order, it is meaningless.

Comment: No, I need to use the condition `records.uniqueID < "9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213"` but it doesn't seem to work (as per comments on other question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `IEnumerable<>` is already ordered, you can use [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx) to skip all that you don't want to have.

Comment: or simply call a where(x=>x.uniqueID < "9522d406-e35d-4b7a-ac18-e750192f3213") ?

Comment: @gillesemmanuel that would evaluate all. The OP mentioned he wanted all from a specific point because he knew it was sorted. If the list was unsorted, you are right.

Comment: @nvoigt still not if you call the where before the order by clause ?

Comment: @gillesemmanuel That's speculation. The OP said it was ordered already. Why or when is nothing I'd care about. Your `Where` would work, too, it would just do too much work on an already ordered collection.

Comment: @nvoigt I get: The Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.